# Getting four points on a closed non-intersecting curve such that they form a square.

Tags: geometry

Prove that in any closed non-intersecting curve there exist four points on the curve such that they make a square.
I have no idea from where to start.

Comment: Good luck, it's a well known unsolved problem. See [inscribed square problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).

Comment: Is this supposed to be a _closed_ curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the [*inscribed square problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem), and it remains an unsolved problem. However, it is true if the curve is *convex* or piecewise *smooth*.

You can read more about the problem at the link to Wikipedia, above, where you'll also find references for further research into the problem and attempts to solve it.